# Create dynamic sql statement based on the output of a select in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, select

I have a function that takes any date and translates it to another date within a different year (the point of it is to preserve the weekday, week number and month, but thats not really relevant). I use it to translate a list of dates and create a temporary table that maps the original date to the mapped date using the function. The query looks like this:

```
Select  InputDates.Date as InputDate, dbo.GetFutureDate(InputDates.Date,2012) as PastDate
        INTO #DateMap
        FROM InputDates
```

InputDates is the list of dates that I need to translate. dbo.GetFutureDate is the translation function.

As you can see the year is hardcoded, which is what I am trying to change. I have a list of years in another table. I want to create a dynamic sql statement with a series of SELECT statements like the one above, changing the year based on the list of years I have and then combine them together using Union All.

What's the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I am understanding you correctly, but why don't you create a cross join with the year list you have and pass the function the year column from the year list.

```
Select  InputDates.Date as InputDate, dbo.GetFutureDate(InputDates.Date,YearInYearList) as PastDate
    INTO #DateMap
    FROM InputDates, YearList
```

YearList is your table name with the years in them, YearInYearList is the column name from the table.  This should produce exactly what you want without the UNION overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Select  InputDates.Date as InputDate, dbo.GetFutureDate(Date.Date,(select year from YourYearTable)) as PastDate
        INTO #DateMap
        FROM Dates

Comment: This does works only if I select one year, like if I do this
Select InputDates.Date as InputDate, dbo.GetFutureDate(Date.Date,(select Top 1 year from YourYearTable)) as PastDate INTO #DateMap FROM Dates

If there are multiple years I get the following message:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APPLY operator in SQL Server to achieve what you want. Basically, the APPLY operator allows you to reference a column from the outer query and it converts to a join or outer join.

Ex:

select y.year, t.*
into #DateMap 
from years as y
cross apply (
    Select  InputDates.Date as InputDate, dbo.GetFutureDate(InputDates.Date, y.year) as PastDate
        FROM InputDates
) as t

See Books Online for more details on the APPLY operator.